# OAuth Changes Break getting Cookies

Tags: php, facebook, cookies, oauth

Using PHP I used to be able to retrieve a cookie for the active user by doing this:

```
 //Returns an array: ([access_token] =>[base_domain] =>[expires] =>[secret] =>[session_key] =>[sig] =>[uid] =>)
    public static function getFacebookCookies() {
      $args = array();
      parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_MY_API_KEY'], '\\"'), $args);
      ksort($args);
      $payload = '';
      foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != 'sig') {
          $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
        }
      }
      if (md5($payload . MY_API_SECRET) != $args['sig']) {
        return false;
      }
      return $args;
}
```

But this no longer seems to work. I'm using the PHP SDK, is there anyway to get these cookies now, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

The cookie fbs_APP_ID is now replaced with fbsr_APP_ID (note the r). The value is now a signed_request rather than containing the access token. If you review the [**docs**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) there is a php example to parse this data to get a JSON array.

Comment: I've been having the same problem as Scott above.  I've changed the cookie to fbsr_ in my code, but there still seem to be some issues using Scott's example above as it throws a php error 'Underfined index: sig' - Scott's function above is pretty much directly copied from FB's developer docs here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login which no longer works and hasn't been updated.  Any idea how to get the example above to work with today's Facebook?

Comment: @Joshua The example is out of date on FB's docs. The value contained in the fbr_APP_ID cookie is a signed request. View the link in my reply above about signed requests. Essentially you take the data part, decode it, get the 'code' parameter and request an access token from:

    https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=&
    client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE. 

Note that I, and others, have found that you need to leave the redirect_uri parameter blank otherwise it fails to give you an access token.